# EventSourcing and DDD Entity events

Tags: events, cross-domain, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

I have a DDD project using EventSourcing. And currently there are many aggregate roots many of which have collections of entities. Even more - some entities have collections of other entities.

Problem: Reading EventSourcing event log for audit purposes.

Question: What is the best way to save events in EventStore when an entity is Updated/Created/Removed having all these things in mind: they have to be easily readable, versions, may be not for this case but usually granular events are preferable, probably domain-events are going to be used for cross domain communication.

1. Should I save in the root stream the whole root with all collections of entities inside as a RootChangedEvent ?
2. Should I save only the entity which was Updated/Created/Removed in the root stream as a EntityChangedEvent/EntityCreatedEvent/EntityRemovedEvent
3. Should I save in the root stream Two events - one for the root - RootChangedEvent with only the version property + second for the entity which will have only a single property if such changed in EntityChangedEvent or whole entity if EntityCreatedEvent or only id if EntityRemovedEvent (How to handle if entity of entity created/updated/removed?)

Here is an example in my project:

The root - Pipeline.

```
public class Pipeline : AggregateRoot<IPipelineState>
```

It has collection of entities - `public IList<Status> Statuses`.

And each Status has collection of entities - `public IList<Logic> Logics`.

All collections could store a lot of entities. And right now I raise events like PipelineCreatedEvent, PipelineChangedEvent (not only when Pipeline changed but even when adding, updating, removing Status or Logic) and PipelineRemovedEvent.

Comment: It is a bad smell if your events are all about CRUD. With Event Sourcing you have flexibility to change your domain model later if your events are business specific, not entity specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should be a single stream of events for any given aggregate, to avoid race conditions. Aggregate is a transaction boundary.

In your case, try to formulate what happened in your system not in terms of Entities, but in business words:

1. OrderCreated (orderId=123)
2. OrderItemAdded (orderId=123, 'product1')
3. OrderItemAdded (orderId=123, 'product2')
4. OrderItemRemoved (orderId=123, 'product1')
5. OrderPaid (orderId=123)
6. OrderArchived (orderId=123)

These events happened with what? With Order so order is your aggregate root, and 123 - its aggregateId. You may not even need OrderItems there, unless this is required by command handler (say, you don't want to emit OrderItemRemoved event for already removed item).

You will have a single event stream for aggregateRoot 123, and nobody can, say, add and OrderItem while you are processing PayOrder command.

It is important to understand that the more business specific your events, the more flexibility you'll have later with domain aggregates and read models. Remember, your events are immutable and will be there forever!

**OrderEntityChangedEvent**(new Status = Paid) implies particular structure of your entities 
**OrderPaid** events assume nothing except there is an Order Aggregate root somewhere.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your answer.

Comment: You should not save any entities in the event stream. You should save events - what happened to your system? And DDD aggregate you restore on the write side from events should contains minimal state to validate command it receives. I cannot imagine you'll need 3 levels of entities to do that. You can build any level-deep readmodel, but aggregates are on write side.
Maybe example would help to understand your use case.

Comment: Added an example in the question describtion above.